# SQL query to get top 24 records, then average the first 12 and bottom 12

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to analyze each account's performance (A_Count & B_Count) during their first year versus their second year. This should only return clients who have at least 24 months of totals (records).

Volume Table

| Account | ReportDate | A_Count | B_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001A | 2019-01-01 | 47 | 100 |
| 1001A | 2019-02-01 | 50 | 105 |
| 1002A | 2019-02-01 | 50 | 105 |

I think I'm on the right track by wanting to grab the top 24 records for each account (only if 24 exist) and then grabbing the top 12 and bottom 12, but not sure how to get there.

I guess ideal output would be:

| Account | YR1_A_Avg | YR1_B_Avg | YR2_A_Avg | YR2_B_Avg | FirstDate | LastDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001A | 47 | 100 | 53 | 115 | 2019-01-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| 1002A | 50 | 105 | 65 | 130 | 2019-02-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1003A | 15 | 180 | 38 | 200 | 2017-05-01 | 2019-04-01 |

I'm not too worried about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no gaps in `ReportDate` (per `Account`).

```
select Account 
      ,avg(case when year_index = 1 then A_Count end) as YR1_A_Avg  
      ,avg(case when year_index = 1 then B_Count end) as YR1_B_Avg  
      ,avg(case when year_index = 2 then A_Count end) as YR2_A_Avg  
      ,avg(case when year_index = 2 then B_Count end) as YR2_B_Avg
      ,min(ReportDate) as FirstDate
      ,max(ReportDate) as LastDate
from  
       (
        select *
              ,count(*)     over(partition by Account) as cnt 
              ,(row_number() over(partition by Account order by ReportDate)-1)/12 +1 as year_index
        from   Volume
       ) t
where cnt >= 24 and year_index <= 2
group by Account
```